# Avoiding using stack memory

Tags: c++, static, stack

I`m developing a project where there is a Receive function which polls HW to see if there is anything received from HDLC. Polling period is 1 ms. And if something is available my software sends an acknowledgement over HDLC to confirm that message is received.

Maximum number of bytes allowed in my protocol is 1000 bytes. Do you think having a locally declared receive buffer with this size is a good idea ? Or should I declare it in my cpp file with static keyword given that variable is only modified in Receive function but nowhere else ?

Comment: Are you on an embedded system? If not then there's really no need to worry about stack space. And even if you are on an embedded system it really depends on the system.

Comment: Yes , it is an embedded system with FreeRTOS. Actually my point  was to save cpu  clock cycles so that it does no have to allocate 1000bytes in every 1ms.  what do you think ?

Comment: When the compiler "allocates" memory on the stack, it's not the same as allocating on the heap, there's no function that is called or pushing onto the stack. Instead the compiler simply generates code that moves a single value into the stack pointer register. It doesn't matter how many local variables you have, or their size, it's still going to be a single write to a single register. What *is* important is the size of your stack, and if you can afford storing such an array on the stack (and with the exception of the smallest systems you can easily store 1000 bytes on the stack).

Answer (score 1):

Since the receiving buffer's lifespan is connected to that of Receiver, I'd recommend putting it as a private field inside Receiver. No need to allocate it in static memory (unless Receiver is there anyway), no need for stack (although it is rather cheap).

The only possible problem is whether the Receiver object is shared between multiple threads, and if so - the shared buffer requires a bit more work.